# Reassigning variable values in java

Tags: javascript, var

I'm having troubles reassigning the values for x & y in order to make them the correct numbers in the console log. While I would love to use additional numbers I have to keep in mind the following rules. 
Rules:

- You may only add lines of code that re-assign values of variables provided.
- You may only add lines of code that re-assign values of variables provided.
- You may only use assignment (=) and arithmetic operators (+ - * /).
- You MAY NOT type or introduce any numbers.
- You MAY NOT change or alter the console.log statement at all.

  ```
  var x = 2;
  var y = 3;
  var z = 0;
  // your code here
  x = (y+z);
  // y = ? 
  console.log("The value of x is: " + x + " (x should be 3)");
  console.log("The value of y is: " + y + " (y should be 2)");
  ```

Comment: Ok. Seriously.. What?

Comment: What are the numbers you are getting right now?

Comment: What is the "y = ();" supposed to be doing?  What values are you getting now?

Comment: I've been trying to make x = 3 using y+z and I can't use y = x since I've already changed the value of x. If I change y first then I have no idea how to change x.

Comment: are you trying to swap x and y? `z=x; x=y; y=z`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but I believe you are looking for a "swap" functionality:

```
var x = 2;
var y = 3;
var z = 0;
// your code here
z = x;  // Temporarily store x in z
x = y;  // Overwrite x with y
y = z;  // Store the original value of x in y
console.log("The value of x is: " + x + " (x should be 3)");
console.log("The value of y is: " + y + " (y should be 2)");
```

Answer (score 0):

first assign z

`z = x`

z is now 2...

`x = y`

x is now 3

`y = z`

y is now 2

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SO35618914 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 15;

        x = x + y;
        y = x - y;
        x = x - y;

        System.out.println("x: " + x + "; y: " + y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to swap `x` and `y` you can do it without `z`

```
var x = 2;
var y = 3;

// swap x and y
x = x + y;
y = x - y;
x = x - y;

console.log("The value of x is: " + x + " (x should be 3)");
console.log("The value of y is: " + y + " (y should be 2)");
```

Output:

The value of x is: 3

The value of y is: 2

Comment: They are given the third variable though, so it seems they are meant to use it.